# How to call requestWindowFeature inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, request

I want to call :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

but the code below does not work:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

     return rootView;
    }//end onCreateView
```

can someone give a hand, pls. thanks

Answer (score 4):

try this in `Fragment`

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Comment: In fragment it's not working. **Error** - _requestFeature() must be called before adding content_